# `ggplot` how to add `lm` fit while preserving colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, colors

[image: scatter plot with desired default colours]

[image: lm]

[image: scatter plot with different colours and lm]

I have some data which consists of values (`value_100`) corresponding to different time horizons.  I wish to fit a linear model through them whilst also having different colours represent each time period in the scatter plot.

The problem is, I can create them both separately, but as soon as I try to combine them, the colour palette changes. This is frustrating, because I would like it to have the same colour palette as the rest of my graphs! I've tried using `ggplot` too, and adding them together in a variety of ways and the same thing keeps happening. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

```
graph <- qplot(Time_period, value_100, data = df,
               geom = c("point"), color = Time_period_factor)
graph <- qplot(Time_Period, value_100, data = df, geom = "smooth")
graph <- qplot(Time_period, value_100, data = df, geom = "smooth") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Time_period, y = value_100), color = df$Time_period_factor)
```

Comment: Try with `geom_point(aes(x = Time_period, y = value_100, color = Time_period_factor))`, i.e. map on the `color` aesthetic inside `aes()`. BTW: Be aware that `qplot` was deprecated in ggplot 3.4.0 "in order to encourage the users to learn ggplot() as it makes it easier to create complex graphics."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bottom Line Up Front

1. move `color=` to *inside* the `aes(..)`; and
2. shift to `ggplot` instead of `qplot` (not a bug, but recommended since `qplot` is deprecated)

```r
graph <- ggplot(df, aes(Time_period, value_100)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_point(aes(color = Time_period_factor))
```

---

It appears the color palettes are different based on where you add `color=` in the call to `geom_point`. When you want to do something like `color=df$..` where `df` is the original plotting data, instead add it as an `aes`thetic, for at least two reasons: (1) this color thing, and (2) a legend. (If you want to suppress the legend, there are ways to do that.)

First, I'll reproduce the *problem* using `mtcars`:

```r
mtcars$cyl_fct <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, geom = "smooth")
qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, geom = "point", color = cyl_fct)
qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, geom = "smooth") +
  geom_point(color = mtcars$cyl_fct)
```

[image: ggplot of mtcars smooth]

[image: ggplot of mtcars points]

[image: ggplot of smooth and points combined, changing palette]

Instead, put `color` inside the `aes`thetic. Note that it inherits the x/y aesthetics from the first call, we don't need to include that.

```r
qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, geom = "smooth") +
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl_fct))
```

[image: ggplot of smooth and points combined, original good palette]

If you are intending to suppress the legend, this can be accomplished by adding `+ guides(color = "none")`.

---

As to ***why*** this is happening, let's look at the build of a grob, specifically the `$data` of it:

```r
gg <- qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, geom = "smooth") + geom_point(color = mtcars$cyl_fct)
lapply(ggplot_build(gg)$data, head)
# `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
# Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_smooth()`).
# [[1]]
#          x        y     ymin     ymax       se flipped_aes PANEL group  colour   fill linewidth linetype weight alpha
# 1 10.40000 466.0586 376.5426 555.5746 43.39325       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60         1        1      1   0.4
# 2 10.69747 456.2379 375.4340 537.0419 39.17006       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60         1        1      1   0.4
# 3 10.99494 446.5080 373.3747 519.6413 35.45167       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60         1        1      1   0.4
# 4 11.29241 436.8767 370.3615 503.3919 32.24351       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60         1        1      1   0.4
# 5 11.58987 427.3521 366.4043 488.2999 29.54467       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60         1        1      1   0.4
# 6 11.88734 417.9420 361.5351 474.3489 27.34347       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60         1        1      1   0.4
# [[2]]
#      x   y PANEL group shape colour size fill alpha stroke
# 1 21.0 160     1    -1    19      6  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
# 2 21.0  NA     1    -1    19      6  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
# 3 22.8  NA     1    -1    19      4  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
# 4 21.4 258     1    -1    19      6  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
# 5 18.7 360     1    -1    19      8  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
# 6 18.1 225     1    -1    19      6  1.5   NA    NA    0.5
```

Notice how the `colour` in the first (smooth) data is hex-colors, and in the second (points) it's the *literal `cyl` values*. This reminds us that when we supply the `color=` argument outside of `aes(.)`, it is treated as color literals. These happen to work because R has a default discrete color palette, which we can see with

```r
plot(1:8, col=1:8, pch=16, cex=4)
### fyi, these are the colors `plot` used
palette()
# [1] "black"   "#DF536B" "#61D04F" "#2297E6" "#28E2E5" "#CD0BBC" "#F5C710" "gray62"
```

[image: base graphics plot of integer colors]

and `ggplot2` is using these literally. Notice that the colors in the incorrect smooth+points plot above correspond to colors 4, 6, and 8, the values of `mtcars$cyl`. (Incidentally, if there are integers above `length(palette())`, they cycle, so `col=9` is the same here as `col=1`, ergo `"black"`.)

Okay, you might say *"but we used `cyl_fct` which is a `factor`, you're right, and ...

```r
str(ggplot_build(gg)$data[[2]])
# `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
# Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_smooth()`).
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  10 variables:
#  $ x     : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  $ y     : num  160 NA NA 258 360 ...
#  $ PANEL : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ group : int  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "n")= int 1
#  $ shape : num  19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 ...
#  $ colour: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
#  $ size  : num  1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 ...
#  $ fill  : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ alpha : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ stroke: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
```

confirms that they are in fact still factors ... but apparently R and/or ggplot2 are out-smarting us by converting those to integers.

We can confirm that this "smartness" is not infallible by passing something that cannot be easily converted to a hex color, a `colors()` name, or a `palette()` index:

```r
qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, geom = "smooth") +
  geom_point(color = LETTERS[mtcars$cyl_fct])
# `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
# Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_smooth()`).
# Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
# Error in geom_point(color = LETTERS[mtcars$cyl_fct]) : 
#   Problem while converting geom to grob.
# ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
# Caused by error:
# ! Unknown colour name: B

qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars, geom = "smooth") + geom_point(color = LETTERS[mtcars$cyl])
# `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
# Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_smooth()`).
# Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
# Error in geom_point(color = LETTERS[mtcars$cyl]) : 
#   Problem while converting geom to grob.
# ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
# Caused by error:
# ! Unknown colour name: F
```

Bottom line, the problem is that you were inadvertently hard-coding the colors because your "color" component `Time_period_factor` happens to look like numbers. Had it been something not-like-a-number, it should have failed instead of trying to out-smart you.